# C# Dynamic object cannot access variable as assigned in base constructor

Tags: c#, inheritance, dynamic, constructor

I have a dynamic object `Type` that I assign via a constructor. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var x = new Shirt("Collared");
}



class Shirt {

    public dynamic Type = new { };

    public string ProblemVariable;

    public Shirt() { }

    public Shirt(string type) {

        ProblemVariable = "Assigned in Constructor";

        if (type == "Collared") {

            Type = new Type.Collared();
        }

}

class Type : Shirt {

    public Type() { }
    public Type(string value)
    {
    }

}

class Collared : Type { }
```

In Main(), calling `x.Type.GetType()` returns that my dynamic `x.Type` is a `Type.Collared`. In `Type.Collared`, I would like to create a function that accesses string `ProblemVariable` from  base class `Shirt`:

```
class Collared : Type {

    public void GetProblemVariable() {
        Console.WriteLine(ProblemVariable);
    }

}
```

Doing so returns a `NullReferenceException`. If I assign `ProblemVariable` as `"Not modified"` in my class definition:

```
class Shirt {

    public string ProblemVariable = "Not modified";
```

My function GetProblemVariable returns `ProblemVariable` as `"Not Modified"`.

While I am obviously able to access `ProblemVariable` from base class `Shirt`, why does `Type.Collared` not return ProblemVariable as `"Assigned in Constructor"` as defined in constructor `Shirt(string type)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Type = new Type.Collared(); calls base constructor public Shirt() { }, not public Shirt(string type), so ProblemVariable is not assigned.

Comment: I solved this by adding a constructor `public Collared(string value) { ProblemVariable = value; } ` and changed `new Type.Collared()` to `new Type.Collared(DataToPass)`, which worked perfectly.